# Facebook singesignon not working in sony and htc devices on SDK 3.5

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I hv recently updated my application to facebook sdk 3.5 everything works fine.. But unfortunately when i tested it with sony Xperia Neo L, HTC Wildfire S and i got an error( Check the attachment). And it works if I signout and try to sighin with my app. Anybody know whats the problem is??[image]

I Successfully tested in Xolo Q900, Galaxy S3, Xperia Z.

Answer (score 1):

Just Update you Facebook App in phone and it will start working

Comment: Go to Google play and install Facebook application

Comment: i did that, it shows the error after download completes

Comment: you can try by installing it from apk because the updated app is compulsory for it.